# Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'previewViewController' on ReplayKit

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, replaykit

I have a project with SpriteKit. I have seen the video of WWDC15 for ReplayKit, but when I want use code, I have this error:

> Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'previewViewController'

I have used this code:

```swift
func levelWillEnd() {
    let sharedRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()
    sharedRecorder.stopRecordingWithHandler {
        (previewViewController, error) -> Void in
        if previewViewController != nil {
            self.previewViewController = previewViewController
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to SpriteKit, but since nobody has tried answering, thought I'd try. So this function: LevelWillEnd, I'm assuming it is located in your previewViewController class right? And GameScene, I'm assuming that's the name of your sks file, right? So, I don't know if this is your problem or if it helps, but I would make sure your sks file and your viewController are linked

Comment: i use only GameScene.swift, and this is the problem, i'm really new, and don't talk to create a previewViewController class or other, but only get me this code, infact don't have anything with previewViewController name, anyway this is the video [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-605/) and Thanks again for your help